# "Error HH100: Network rinkeby doesn't exists

Tags: solidity, nft, hardhat, rinkeby, alchemy

I am running through [learnweb3.io](https://learnweb3.io/courses/9a3fafe4-b5eb-4329-bdef-97b2aa6aacc1/lessons/017e65bf-2a86-455e-a499-09b61ffa5241) 'Build your own simple NFT tutorial' and I keep getting the error: `Error HH100: Network rinkeby doesn't exist`

This is what my `deploy.js` file looks like:

```
// Import ethers from Hardhat package
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  /*
A ContractFactory in ethers.js is an abstraction used to deploy new smart contracts,
so nftContract here is a factory for instances of our GameItem contract.
*/
  const nftContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("GameItem");

  // here we deploy the contract
  const deployedNFTContract = await nftContract.deploy();
  
  // wait for the contract to deploy
  await deployedNFTContract.deployed();

  // print the address of the deployed contract
  console.log("NFT Contract Address:", deployedNFTContract.address);
}

// Call the main function and catch if there is any error
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

And this is what my `hardhat.config.js` file looks like:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });

const ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL = process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL;
const RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL,
      accounts: [RINKEBY_PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
};
```

Please I need help on how to fix this error.

Comment: Your error says "Rinkbey", misspelled. Is the incorrect network name being used somewhere else? Or was this just a copy/paste mistake? If you're running this in hardhat cli and inputting network parameter, make sure it's spelled right!